# Attempting to write code for a simple calculator. Trouble getting the program to solve the equation that the user inputs

Tags: java, swing, calculator

Currently when user presses buttons on the calculator it displays value on the text box above, but I just cannot get it to solve the equation. Every button that is pressed displays in the TextField but when I press '=' (equals) I would like it so that it solves the equation. Could you help me with this problem please?

```
//Michael Moradi
//Period C1
//June 2, 2015
//Final Project Semester 2

import javax.swing.*; //imports all that is needed for the code

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16;
    public JTextArea text; //makes these accessible throughout the code

    public Calculator()
    {
        setSize(350,300); //sets size to 300 by 300
        setResizable(false); //does not let user change the size of the window
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//makes app close when I press the x on the top left

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();//gets the contentPane
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);//sets background color to white         

        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//makes the contentPane read from left to right

        text = new JTextArea(1, 25);
        contentPane.add(text);
        text.setEditable(false);

        button1 = new JButton ("7");
        contentPane.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(this);

        button2 = new JButton ("8");
        contentPane.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(this);

        button3 = new JButton ("9");
        contentPane.add(button3);
        button3.addActionListener(this);

        button4 = new JButton ("÷");
        contentPane.add(button4);
        button4.addActionListener(this);

        button5 = new JButton ("4");
        contentPane.add(button5);
        button5.addActionListener(this);

        button6 = new JButton ("5");
        contentPane.add(button6);
        button6.addActionListener(this);

        button7 = new JButton ("6");
        contentPane.add(button7);
        button7.addActionListener(this);

        button8 = new JButton ("x");
        contentPane.add(button8);
        button8.addActionListener(this);

        button9 = new JButton ("1");
        contentPane.add(button9);
        button9.addActionListener(this);

        button10 = new JButton ("2");
        contentPane.add(button10);
        button10.addActionListener(this);

        button11 = new JButton ("3");
        contentPane.add(button11);
        button11.addActionListener(this);

        button12 = new JButton ("-");
        contentPane.add(button12);
        button12.addActionListener(this);

        button13 = new JButton ("0");
        contentPane.add(button13);
        button13.addActionListener(this);

        button14 = new JButton ("C");
        contentPane.add(button14);
        button14.addActionListener(this);

        button15 = new JButton ("=");
        contentPane.add(button15);
        button15.addActionListener(this);

        button16 = new JButton ("+");
        contentPane.add(button16);
        button16.addActionListener(this);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator guiWindow = new Calculator(); //uses GUI
        guiWindow.setVisible(true); //makes it visible

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        String enteredNumbers = text.getText();

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("7"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("7"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("8"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("8"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("9"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("9"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("÷"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("÷"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("4"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("4"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("5"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("5"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("6"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("6"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("x"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("x"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("1"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("1"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("2"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("2"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("3"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("3"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("-"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("-"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("0"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("0"));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("C"))
        text.setText("");

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("="))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("="));

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("+"))
        text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("+"));




    }

}
```

Comment: Might just be me, but it looks like your code only sets text when the = button is pressed.  Do you have any code pertaining to equation solving?

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Comment: A calculation is a group of `{value}{operator}{value}`, you need to generate these groups and perform the calculation, don't forget, order of precedence

Comment: BTW `text = new JTextArea(1, 25);` should probably better be `text = new JTextField(25);` (with appropriate changes in the declaration of the `text` field).

Comment: @MadProgrammer , If I had a string with format `{value}{operator}{value}` like `"11-1"`, how would I parse the string into `int num1`,`char operator` and `int num2` so that each variable will hold `11`,`'-'` and `1`? Is there a function to do it?

Comment: `String#split` might be my first port of call

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you simply want to change your `ActionListener`. Every other button—which I strongly encourage you to give more meaningful names, by the way—simply adds a token of text to the calculator field. "=" is meant, by your description, to solve it. So,

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("="))
    text.setText(enteredNumbers + ("="));
```

should be more like this:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("=")) {
    String math = text.getText();
    answerField.setText(solve(math));
}

private solve(String math) {
    //This is the tricky part, see description next.
}
```

For your solving method, I would suggest one of two things. The first would be to break it down with a series of [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), which you can create and try out (before implementing) [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). From there, you will know whether a provided field will be a number, or an operator. Operators are often best paired with enumerations and `Function` fields. Unfortunately, this still leaves the question of how to handle operator precedence open.

For that, you'll want to break it down into [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation); with something like the [Shunting-Yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). After that, you can just step through and apply each operation function in the order it appears.

If you're in a hurry, you could probably also use the Java Scripting Engine and simply implement your math as solvable JavaScript; a tutorial available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/). Currently, Javascript/ECMAscript is available, but I'm sure there are plenty of others available through external libraries. (When you're dealing with frequently changing dynamic code, it's a godsend.)

Hopefully one of these resources will help you. I actually once implemented a script in Java that specifically focused on solving mathematical equations, using the first method; and now just plug it in to new applications with the second method. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, using the JavaScript library math.js via a Java Script Engine. You can download the file math.js from: http://mathjs.org/download.html

```
package org.mathjs;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class MathJS {
    protected static String MATHJS_SCRIPT = "./lib/mathjs/math.js";
    protected ScriptEngine engine;

    public MathJS () throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager ();
        engine = manager.getEngineByName ("js");

        engine.eval(new FileReader(MATHJS_SCRIPT));
        engine.eval("var parser = math.parser();");
        engine.eval("var precision = 14;");
    }

    public String eval (String expr) throws ScriptException {
        String script = "math.format(parser.eval('" + expr + "'), precision);";
        return (String) engine.eval(script);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException {
        MathJS math = new MathJS();
        System.out.println(math.eval("a = 4.5"));
        System.out.println(math.eval("1.2 * (2 + a)"));
        System.out.println(math.eval("5.08 cm in inch"));
        System.out.println(math.eval("sin(45 deg) ^ 2"));   
        System.out.println(math.eval("9 / 3 + 2i") );   
        System.out.println(math.eval("det([-1, 2; 3, 1])"));
    }
}
```